# Sumar entradas y salidas usuarios en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla SQL:


[image: Tabla registros usuarios]

Y necesitaria obtener algo parecido a esto:

[image: Resultado]

Es decir, sumar las horas agrupadas por fecha, he probado diferentes opciones, pero ni si quiera se acercan al resultado esperado...

Intentos fallidos:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(U.usuari, R.idUsuari) AS Usuari, R.IdRegistre, R.IdregistreS, CAST(R.Entrada AS smalldatetime) AS Entrada, CAST(R.Sortida AS smalldatetime) AS Sortida, R.TempsEnHores,  R.TempsEnMinuts
FROM  (SELECT  IdUsuari AS idUsuari, IdRegistre, IdRegistreS AS IdregistreS, ISNULL(Projecte, '') AS Referencia, ISNULL(Traspassat, 0) AS Traspassat, DataRegistre AS Entrada, 
           ISNULL(DataRegistreS, DataRegistre) AS Sortida, FORMAT(DATEDIFF(minute, DataRegistre, ISNULL(DataRegistreS, DataRegistre)) / 60.0, 'N2') AS TempsEnHores, 
           FORMAT(DATEDIFF(second, DataRegistre, ISNULL(DataRegistreS, DataRegistre)) / 60.0, 'N2') AS TempsEnMinuts
        FROM  (SELECT IdUsuari, IdRegistre, Projecte, Traspassat, DataRegistre,
                (SELECT        TOP (1) DataRegistre
                    FROM            vRegistreCorretgit AS V1
                    WHERE        (IdUsuari = V2.IdUsuari) AND (Moviment = 'S') AND (DataRegistre > V2.DataRegistre)
                    ORDER BY DataRegistre) AS DataRegistreS,
                (SELECT        TOP (1) IdRegistre
                    FROM            vRegistreCorretgit AS V1
                    WHERE        (IdUsuari = V2.IdUsuari) AND (Moviment = 'S') AND (DataRegistre > V2.DataRegistre)
                    ORDER BY DataRegistre) AS IdRegistreS
                FROM  vRegistreCorretgit AS V2
            WHERE (Moviment = 'E')) AS Entrades) AS R LEFT  JOIN dbo.Usuaris AS U ON R.idUsuari = U.Id                
WHERE idUsuari = 34
```

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes poner el código de lo que has intentando @IvanOrtega?

Comment: @DevCodeG Ya esta, disculpa! Como veras logro juntar entradas y salidas, pero no los puedo agrupar por dia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que lo quisieras saber es, entre entradas y salidas, cual fue la diferencia en horas, en formato decimal, de lo que dicho usuario hizo en tal fecha.

Siendo así, y con el ejemplo que pones de tabla, el siguiente código satisface el requerimiento:

```
WITH cteHorasE
AS
(
SELECT 
    CONVERT(date, Hora) as Fecha, 
    IDUsuario,
    CONVERT(time, Hora) as HoraE,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Hora ASC) AS IdE
FROM Horarios
WHERE Movimiento = 'E'
),

cteHorasS
AS
(
SELECT 
    CONVERT(date, Hora) as Fecha, 
    IDUsuario,
    CONVERT(time, Hora) as HoraS,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Hora ASC) AS IdS
FROM Horarios
WHERE Movimiento = 'S'
)

SELECT
    CE.Fecha,
    CE.IDUsuario,
    SUM(ROUND(DATEDIFF(MI,CE.HoraE,CS.HoraS)/60.0, 2)) AS Dif_En_Horas
FROM
    cteHorasE CE
INNER JOIN cteHorasS CS ON CE.IDUsuario = CS.IDUsuario AND CE.Fecha = CS.Fecha AND CE.IdE = CS.IdS
GROUP BY
    CE.Fecha,
    CE.IDUsuario
```

En el ejemplo anterior, la tabla se llama [Horarios] y tiene los campos con los mismos nombres que pusiste en el ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

prueba con la siguiente consulta usando CTE y conversiones de algunas columnas:

```
with cteHoras
as
    (select convert(date, Hora) as Fecha, 
            IDUsuario,
            convert(time, Hora) as Hora
    from Carga )
select Fecha, IDUsuario, sum(datediff(ms, '00:00:00.000',Hora) / 3600000.00) as Horas
from cteHoras
group by Fecha, IDUsuario
```

Comment: Se agradece tu ayuda, pero en SO. Funcionamos colocando el problema a resolver y lo que se ha intentado, el OP no muestra intento alguno te sugiero leer [answer]

Comment: @AlfredoPaz Disculpa, ya he añadido el intento que mas se acerca a lo que quiero aconseguir, soy nuevo por aqui y aún me falta un poco de practica.

Comment: Elena, he probado con tu codigo, pero no me acaban de cuadrar las horas, he probado con una modificación "sum(datediff(ms, '00:00:00.000',Hora) / 3600000.00)" ->  "sum(datediff(ms, '00:00:00.000',Hora) / 360000.00)/60" pero el resultado no es coherente